# Scheduling Repeating Daily Jobs with Agenda.js and Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, agenda

I am setting up a job scheduler using Agenda.js and Node, backed with MongoDB. So far it's working as expected. However, I'm unclear how to schedule a repeating job -- for instance, a job that should run every day at 9am.

"schedule" is used for a one-time scheduling of a job, but not repeats:

```
agenda.schedule('today at 09:00am CST', 'first job');
```

"every" works with an interval like "3 minutes", but not with "day at 9:00am"

```
agenda.every('3 minutes', 'second job');
```

Since configuration methods are supposedly chainable I also tried this:

```
agenda.processEvery('24 hours').schedule('day at 09:45am CST', 'second job');
```

... this did run the task successfully the first time 9:45am CST arrived, but it didn't reset it to run the next day at the same time.

What syntax would I use to run a job EVERY day at 9:00am? And, even better, how can I schedule that to run on Monday - Friday only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ajenda accepts `cron` format. So you can do something like this

This is repeat Job **At 09:00 on every day-of-week from Monday through Friday**

```
job.repeatEvery('0 9 * * 1-5', {
    skipImmediate: true
});
```

`SkipImmediate` is Optional. Here is [CRON checker](https://crontab.guru/#0_9_*_*_1-5) for above `cron` string. Read more about [repeatEvery](https://github.com/agenda/agenda#repeateveryinterval-options)

**EDIT**

`Job` is returned when `Agenda` is made

```
agenda.define('NAME', async job => {
            job.repeatEvery('0 9 * * 1-5', {
                skipImmediate: true
            });
            await job.save()
        }
```

Read more about [Creating Jobs](https://github.com/agenda/agenda#creating-jobs)

Comment: Thanks, but I get an `agenda.repeatEvery is not a function` error when I try this.

Comment: This is what I tried: `agenda.repeatEvery('* 9 * * 1-5', {
      skipImmediate: true
    });`

Comment: Yes because `repeatEvery` is available on `job` not `agenda`. `Job` is what `agenda` returns

Comment: Right. And would one need to chain on a `save()` to get this to persist to the database? What would that look like?

Comment: Yup you got the Idea! Read about it [here](https://github.com/agenda/agenda#createjobname-data)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar use case, but I did not want to use a `cron` string.

```
const agendaEvery = async (interval, sendTime, name, data, options) => {
  const job = agenda
    .create(name, data)
    .repeatEvery(interval, {
      timezone: 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur',
      skipImmediate: true,
      startDate: sendTime
    })
    .schedule(sendTime)
  await job.save()
}
```

This will allow say you want to send a daily email, you can use a ISO formatted datetime string to schedule the first one, and the interval can be for .e.g `1 day`.

Comment: Great solution. I'm not clear on how to incorporate it with the agenda.every because they require (interval, name, data, options)? So if I do

Answer (score 0):

Using `skipImmediate: true`  with `repeatEvery`, I got a typescript error. The line

```
agenda.every('0 9 * * 1-5', cronTypes.PUSH, null, {skipImmediate: true});
```

worked

Answer (score 0):

The approved solution seems a bit funky. I feel calling `job.repeatEvery()` within the job handler is kind of out of its place.

**agenda.every** accepts `cron` format, therefore you can apply it to any defined job and run the handler according to the `cron` sequence

You have a defined job:

```
agenda.define('do-something', async (job, done) => {
  // Doing some heavy async stuff here
  async heavyStuff();
  done();
})
```

**After server initialisation** you can call it anywhere in your code to setup a repeated job. Just make sure `await agenda.start()` was already called and agenda has an established mongo connection

```
await agenda.every("0 9 * * 1-5", "do-something");
```